# SQL Select Query Trouble with unique values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having a problem getting a query to work like I need it to. I need to make a sheet of labels for a mailer and only want to select people who don't have email address. Further I only want to send 1 mailer to each address/family. The following select statement returns all the fields I need.

```
SELECT [Family Members].[Family ID]
        ,[Family Members].[First Name]
        ,[Family Members].[Last Name]
        ,[Family Members].Email
        ,[Master Record].[Address 1]
        ,[Master Record].[Address 2]
        ,[Master Record].City
        ,[Master Record].STATE
        ,[Master Record].Zipcode
    FROM [Master Record]
    LEFT JOIN [Family Members] 
    ON [Master Record].[Family ID] = [Family Members].[Family ID];
```

Now a bit about my tables. the "Family ID" is a key and each unique Family ID has a unique address. However each family has multiple members contained in the [Family Members] table each family member may/may not have an email address. If any member of a family has an email address listed I don't want to send a paper mailer and I want them removed from the table. I also don't want to see multiple results in the query based on the "Family ID"

So to be clear the results of this query should have unique "Family ID" values and have no family members with email addresses on file.

I hope this is possible. Thanks.

Comment: Your are using SQL Server/Sybase/MS Access syntax conventions and your question is labelled MySQL.  Which database are you really using?

Comment: It is a Microsoft access database. Sorry forgot to add that bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to have worked for me. Though I'm a bit uneasy about the use of all the Max() functions. I'll go ahead and post this here and see if someone has a more elegant solution.

```
SELECT [Master Record].[Family ID], Max([Master Record].[Last Name]) AS [MaxOfLast Name], 
Max([Master Record].[Address 1]) AS [MaxOfAddress 1], Max([Master Record].[Address 2]) AS 
[MaxOfAddress 2], Max([Master Record].City) AS MaxOfCity, Max([Master Record].State) AS 
MaxOfState, Max([Master Record].Zipcode) AS MaxOfZipcode, Max([Family Members].Email) AS 
MaxOfEmail
FROM [Master Record] LEFT JOIN [Family Members] ON [Master Record].[Family ID] = [Family 
Members].[Family ID]
GROUP BY [Master Record].[Family ID]
HAVING (((Count([Family Members].Email))=0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a

```
GROUP BY [Family Members].[Family ID]
  HAVING COUNT([Family Members].Email) = 0
```

Bear in mind, this will return an undetermined Family Member's details in the case where there is more than one Member in a Family that has no Members with emails.

Also, you probably want to use a `JOIN` not a `LEFT JOIN` to exclude Master Records with no Family Members.

Comment: It looks like I have to put all the fields in the group by statement or it throws an error. In that case it doesn't seem to eliminate the duplicate entries based on family ID.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, answered this qu when it was tagged `MySQL`